Why is it returning me Recipes as and empty array?
I am making an app in Laravel and Vue, when I put the ingredients in my seach bar it returns me empty array of recipes even tho I intentionaly made it that it return me one. This is my SearchController.php
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->query('query');
        $ingredients = explode(",", $query);
        $ingredients = array_map('strtolower', $ingredients);
        $ingredients = array_map('trim', $ingredients);
        $ingredientIds = Ingredient::whereIn('name', $ingredients)->pluck('id');
        $recipeIds = RecipeIngredient::whereIn('ingredient_id', $ingredientIds)->pluck('recipe_id');
        $recipes = Recipe::whereIn('id', $recipeIds)->get();

        return response()->json([
            'ingredients' => $ingredients, 
            'recipes' => $recipes, 

        ]);
    }

Recipe.php
public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredient::class, 'recipes_ingredients', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id');
    }

    public function recipeIngredients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RecipeIngredient::class);
    }

Ingredient.php
protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Recipe::class, 'recipes_ingredients', 'ingredient_id', 'recipe_id');
    }

    public function ingredientRecipes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RecipeIngredient::class);
    }

RecipeIngredient.php
protected $table = 'recipes_ingredients';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function recipe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Recipe::class);
    }

    public function ingredient()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ingredient::class);
    }

It is supposed to give me all the recipes with that ingredient but I get nothing. I gave ChatGPT a chance to debug it and it made it 10x worst will tons of errors. If you need I will provide aditonal code

Since we don't know your query or your table, you're going to have to do some debugging. My favorite way to debug in Laravel is to use Log::info();, which adds the details to your log in storage/logs. Try Log::info($ingredients); Log::info($ingredientIds); Log::info($recipeIds); and see where you're missing the data.

Can you share the url paramters which you are searching for?

It looks like your code logic is mostly correct, but a few potential issues might be causing your problem, Ensure that the query parameter is correctly passed in the request. Add a debug log:
\Log::info('Search query: ' . $query);

Also you can add a log to verify the ID's fetched from DB
\Log::info('Ingredient IDs: ' . $ingredientIds);

may be the ingredient table or the recipes_ingredients is empty, also could be a typos on query.
